# My global variable is not transferring to Dialog Form when called from Report

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Update 3/15/19 to add new declaration code in General Declarations section:

```
Option Compare Database  
  ' Access global variables definition  
   Global bInReportOpenEvent As Boolean  

   Option Explicit
```

I am getting error:

"The expression On Open you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Pubblic members of object modules."

Update 3/15/19 to add declaration code. Still bInReportOpenEvent value lost on call to Dialog form.

```
Option Compare Database    
   Dim bInReportOpenEvent As Boolean    

Function IsLoaded(strNme As String) As Boolean    

   IsLoaded = CurrentProject.AllForms(strNme).IsLoaded  

End Function
```

I am creating an Access Report that calls a Dialog Form to prompt for specific record to display in report.  The report uses a query as the record source. I am setting a global field in the Report Open module so that the Dialog Form cannot be executed on it's own.  If the Dialog Form is called and the global field set by the Report is not set, then I want to exit out with a message.  My Report Open module looks like this:

```
Public Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim outCome1 As String  
' Set public variable to true to indicate that the report  
' is in the Open event  
bInReportOpenEvent = True  
MsgBox (bInReportOpenEvent)  
' Open Appt Query Dialog  
DoCmd.OpenForm "craid CMM Client Report Dialog", , , , , acDialog  

' Cancel Report if User Clicked the Cancel Button  
If IsLoaded("craid CMM Client Report Dialog") = False Then Cancel = True

MsgBox ("Is Dialog Form Loaded?")  
 MsgBox (IsLoaded("craid CMM Client Report Dialog"))  
'outCome1 = (Reports("CMM Client Status    Report").Controls("googleoutcome").Value) 
'MsgBox (outCome1)    

' Set public variable to false to indicate that the  
' Open event is completed  

bInReportOpenEvent = False  
End Sub
```

My Form Open for my Dialog Form looks like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)    
If Not bInReportOpenEvent Then  
MsgBox ("In Not bInReportOpenEvent Logic")  
MsgBox (bInReportOpenEvent)  

' If we're not called from the report  
  MsgBox "For Use From CMM Client Status Report Only", _    
  vbOKOnly  
  Cancel = True  
End If  

End Sub
```

Any ideas on why? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` in all your code modules?  Where and how is `bInReportOpenEvent` declared?

Comment: No, I don't. I am not declaring bInReportOpenEvent.  How should I declare it?

Comment: If you add `Option Explicit` then you will get warnings about things like this, instead of your code failing quietly...   You need `Dim bInReportOpenEvent As Boolean` in a module outside of any Sub or Function.

Comment: I added declaration just after Option Compare Database (General) and updated my post to add that code.  Is a module any code to include Function , Sub, or General?

Comment: Did you add `Option Explicit`?

Comment: ...and where did you declare the Global variable?

Comment: I wasn't sure where to add Option Explicit, but I just did and I got an error that it was not known to the Dialog Form.  I just added it there outside of any Sub or Function in the General Declarations portion.  The value is still not transferring from the report to the form.

Comment: So in the General Declarations for Report and Dialog Form, I have 3 lines of code:
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim bInReportOpenEvent As Boolean

Comment: It should be at the top of every module, with any other `Option ...` statements.  If you're getting errors, it's useful to post the exact text - that can be more informative.  And it would be worth your while checking out some online resources such as https://blueclawdatabase.com/tutorials/vba-global-variables/ and http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html for example

Comment: You only declare your Global variable **once**, typically in a regular code module

Comment: Thank you for the online resources links. I checked them out and have declared a global variable bInReportOpenEvent as defined in updated post.

Comment: Your Global variable goes in a *regular code module* - not in your Form module etc.

Comment: That fixed it! I put the declaration in a VBA module and it's working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered. Solution is to put declaration of global variable in VBA code module.